# WCF client times out but only when using Windows Authentication

Tags: .net, wcf

I have a client server application that uses WCF with NetTcpBinding. The server may be told to use Windows Authentication using the default security.mode "Transport". Or it may be told to use "None" which means the applicaiton uses its own internal security

When the user starts the client application it connects to the server passing the user's current credentials. Depending on the response/exception it receives it will know if
(a) the server is using Windows Authentication and the passed credentials have been accepted
(b) the server is using Windows Authentication and the passed credentials are invalid
(c) the server is not using Windows Authentication

This normally works perfectly however on one customer installation we have the problem where when the client connects to the server no response is received and it times out. However it only does this if Windows Authentication is selected. If not (and internal security is selected) then it works reliably.

The customer has the clients and server in different security domains and the expected behaviour in this instance is that the client will call the server, the server will reject the credentials and the exception will be returned to the client. (the client will then ask the users for credentials and remake the call)

I have enabled WCF tracing on both the client and server. On the server I can see the request being received and I can see the SecurityNegotiationException "The server has rejected the client credentials." generated.

However the client does not receive the response. Instead, after the timeout period expires a System.TimeoutException "The open operation did not complete within the allotted timeout of 00:00:10. The time allotted to this operation may have been a portion of a longer timeout." is generated (I have tried with a longer timeout to no avail).

So for some reason the response is not getting back to the client.

I cannot work out how to diagnose further. I have never seen this before and WCF normally just works reliably. Could it be an issue with networks or firewall? What I can't understand is why it works if Security.Mode is set to None.

It also works if the client is installed on the server and it is not crossing security domains.

I would really appreciate ideas and assistance

UPDATE:

I have done some network tracing using netsh and by chance in the trace session managed to catch an occasion where a call worked and also an occasion where the call failed (timed out). Analysing the messages looks like 2 TCP messages sent from the server have not been received by the client. However the server thinks that they have been acknowledged. Now trying to get network specialists to look at the traces

Comment: this will happen if the client and server are in different domain. you need to trusted domain

Comment: That's not true. If the domains do not have trust then the credentials do not get passed between them - in which case the credentials will always effectively be null and you get an appropriate invalid credentials exception. It has worked previously in this scenario using .NET 3.5 but 6 months later and with a build on .NET 4 it no longer works.